# Burn 1 to 1 copy of a DVD

Tags: backup, dvd, burning, brasero

I know that I can use Brasero to normally burn a DVD from an ISO. But here is my issue, I am backing up my DVD collection and when I use Brasero to rip a DVD I turn it into an ISO that is 7.0GB or larger. Sadly blank DVD's are only 4.7 GB.

My question is how do I use Brasero to create a hadrcopy back up of a DVD, do i need to use a dual layer disk or is there a program out there that will compress the size down to DVD size?

Simply put how do I make a back up of one of my DVD's?

Comment: I would suggest you use k3b for your disk burning. One thing to say though, you do not need another DVD burner to make a copy. I will just copy the file on the computer, store it in a temporary location, and then transfer it to the new disk.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your other question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/308721/burn-a-dvd-from-an-iso?

Comment: Do you mind telling us what is the native disk size of your original media? are they movies? data? This is important because of certain Video DVD's comes in dual layer DVD which size may be different than the 4.7 GB and can reach 17.08 GB

Comment: They are DVD movies... would the dual layer disk be the best?

Comment: You should give a try to a dual layer disk if your DVD burner is dual layer recording capable. I think your problem itself is in the disc space and not the software. Please inform on your experiences in order to document and follow up your issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try K9Copy.

K9Copy facilitates several methods for backing up a DVD.

The software enables direct backup of a single layer DVD-5 provided the user's computer has a DVD recorder. Likewise, direct backup of a dual layer DVD-9 is possible with a dual layer DVD recorder.

K9Copy is able to fit the contents of a dual layer DVD-9 onto a single layer DVD-5.

To download just click [**k9copy** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](http://sourceforge.net/projects/k9copy/files/k9copy-kde4/2.3.8/k9copy-2.3.8-Source.tar.gz/download).

For information on how to install .tar.gz, see [How to install a .tar.gz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

<sup>Source:K9copy</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can convert first by using [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to compress the file and then burn using by using burning app that you like.

[image]

It has many features and works for me.

Comment: x264 RF18 for the win